# Cannot install tiny_tds on os.x 10.9.4

Tags: ruby, macos, freetds, tiny-tds

I'm trying to install tiny_tds on a mac running OS.X Mavericks but I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing tiny_tds:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb gem install tiny_tds -- --without-iconvlib --with-freetds-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91/lib --with-freetds-include=/usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.91/include
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -lfalse... no
-----
libiconv is missing.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

I'm using the following command to install tiny_tds:

```
sudo gem install tiny_tds -- --with-freetds-include=/usr/local/include --with-freetds-lib=/usr/local/lib --with-iconv-include=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/include --with-iconv-lib=/usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib
```

I have looked into `iconv.h` and there is no `iconv_open()` method.

By the way, I'm using ruby 2.0.0p451

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after updating to ruby 2.1.2